# How to use ScrollRestoration on React Router DOM v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've created my router such as recommended in RRDv6 documentation:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Base />,
        children: [
            {
                index: 'true',
                element: <Home />
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                element: <About/>
            },
            {
                path: 'contato',
                element: <Contact />
            },
            {
                path: '*',
                element: <Error404 />
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

In App.jsx, I've put , but it doesn't work:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <DataProvider>
            <RouterProvider router={router}>
                <ScrollRestoration />
            </RouterProvider>
        </DataProvider>
    )
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How do I restore the scroll when change the route.

OBS.: At this moment I'm using `scrollToTop`, but I think this is not the better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [`RouterProvider`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider) doesn't consume any `children` prop:

> ```
> declare function RouterProvider(
>   props: RouterProviderProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface RouterProviderProps {
>   fallbackElement?: React.ReactNode;
>   router: Router;
>   future?: Partial<FutureConfig>;
> }
> ```

The `ScrollRestoration` component should be rendered within the router, near the root.

I suggest rendering it as part of the root layout route component, `Base`.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Outlet />
      ...
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Base />, // <-- renders scroll restoration
    children: [
      ....
    ]
  }
])
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did this and still doesn't work. 

Comment: @RenanSantos This should be about all you need to do to render the `ScrollRestoration` component. What is the issue you have still?